# Select and display image(s) using FileReader

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my problem, i have this little code to display img that i'm uploading LIVE without reload, but it works only with one img because `readURL(input)` doesn't have a class and works directly from noname-input, and when i'm adding a class `readURL(input.joint)`, it drops error! Here is my code:

```
    <input class="joint" type='file' id="imgInp" />
    <img style="width:45px" id="blah" src="#" alt="your image" />


<script type="text/javascript">
function readURL(input) {

    if (input.filers && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#blah').attr('src', e.target.result);
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}

$("#imgInp").change(function(){
    readURL(this);
});
</script>
```

I need to add some id or class to this jquery function to make it unique to every input.

What i'm trying to do:

```
<input class="joint" type='file' id="imgInp" />
        <img style="width:45px" id="blah" src="#" alt="your image" />


    <script type="text/javascript">
    function readURL(input.joint) {

        if (input.joint.filers && input.joint.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function (e) {
                $('#blah').attr('src', e.target.result);
            }

            reader.readAsDataURL(input.joint.files[0]);
        }
    }

    $("#imgInp").change(function(){
        readURL(this);
    });
    </script>


<input class="file2" type='file' id="imgInp" />
        <img style="width:45px" id="blah" src="#" alt="your image" />


    <script type="text/javascript">
    function readURL(input.file2) {

        if (input.file2.filers && input.file2.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function (e) {
                $('#blah').attr('src', e.target.result);
            }

            reader.readAsDataURL(input.file2.files[0]);
        }
    }

    $("#imgInp").change(function(){
        readURL(this);
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: It's not very clear what you're trying to do. What is the error you're getting?

Comment: with error i mean nothing is working :( sorry for my english, maybe i cant explain correctly my problem! input in function needs to be with id or class

Comment: What are you expecting from this: `readURL(input.joint)`?

Comment: if you copy and paste this function twice, it will display only one picture from one input because it's working directly with last <INPUT>

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have duplicate ids all over (`imgInp` and `blah`), so the selector will select only the first one, eventually your event is bound only to the first input field and the selection of `$('#blah')` as well. You need to select the relative image with respect to the input. You dont have to duplicate the script as well. Select the next image tag relative to the input like `$(input).next('img').attr('src', e.target.result);`

So try:

```
function readURL(input) {

    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $(input).next('img').attr('src', e.target.result);
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}


$(function(){   
    $(".upld").change(function () { //set up a common class
        readURL(this);
    });
});
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gd8Cu/)**

Comment: yes, for me this works better cause i'm trying to buld facebook-alike uploading system without any flash, this is a big problem of my web-site, temporary photo-import works like s**t, so needed better solution! jquery was answer, works like magic ;) now i need something like X to delete, next chalange! but with your solution, it will be easyer to do delete and other stuff!

Comment: @user2784722 never duplicate ids in your code. Infact use id's sparingly especially when dealing jquery you can use class names to target elements. Also try to separate the scripts out of the markup and place your selections inside document.ready. Here it worked because your script comes after the element in DOM.

Comment: i'm new to jquery, so every your advice will be great! today i'll have a long night of working it out!

Comment: @user2784722 ENjoy!! Happy conding... :)

Answer (score 2):

Ok, the fact that you are trying to add a class to a function argument with dot notation illustrates that you need to learn more about how Javascript works than can be explained in a simple StackOverflow answer, but let me try:

- `input` in `readURL(input)` is an argument name, similar to a variable name, so you cannot extend it in any way.  It is a reference to whatever you pass in when you call `readURL`, in this case, if you look at the end of your code, it is a reference to `this`.  `this` refers to the elements referenced by the jQuery selector you passed in: `"#imgInp"`.

So, if you want to use the `.joint` class instead, just pass that in as a jQuery selector:

```
$(".joint").change(function(){
    readURL(this);
});
```

- However, assuming you have multiple `.joint` elements, your `readURL` function will no longer work correctly because it is currently designed to only change the `src` of `#blah`.  What you need to do is change the `src` of each elements corresponding `img`.

So, if you had some HTML like this:

```
<input class="joint" type='file' />
<img class="joint-img" style="width:45px" src="#" alt="your image" />

<input class="joint" type='file' />
<img class="joint-img" style="width:45px" src="#" alt="your image" />

<input class="joint" type='file' />
<img class="joint-img" style="width:45px" src="#" alt="your image" />
```

You could place your your `readURL` function after all the elements and alter the `reader.onload` section as follows:

```
function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $(input).next('.joint-img').attr('src', e.target.result);
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}

$(".joint").change(function(){
    readURL(this);
});
```

Comment: A much more detailed answer, nice one.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works correctly for me when I fix the typo:

```
if (input.filers && input.files[0]) {
          ^^^^^^
if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
```

Here is the example: http://jsfiddle.net/s6ttw/

**Update**:

If you want it to work how you expect you need to use classes, rather than ids.

Here's a better example of what you're asking for: http://jsfiddle.net/s6ttw/1/

Comment: my code is working, i know that, but if i want multiple images displaying on one page? so that's my case.

Comment: WOW! amazing, can you explain how you did this?

Comment: PSL also wrote up the same solution, so you can have a look at that for the description of how this works :)

Comment: @Jivings i did not write same solution, but infact i wrote it before you edited to fix your answer..:) Edit history shows it all..

Comment: @PSL They were quite close together, but yes you beat me. I wasn't suggesting otherwise.

Comment: I will give your +1.. :) since both were close